# How to import custom google fonts in NextJS 13? Link tags not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-fonts

I am trying to use *Google Fonts* on a **Nextjs** project with the newest **version 13** and I can't import Google Fonts (i.e. Poppins) correctly.

In the past I just added the link tags to the `_document.js` or `_app.js` file and that was it.

I am trying it this way without success:

```
  <Head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  </Head>
```

In the past, an alternative was to import the Google fonts on the global CSS stylesheet with @import but this method doesn't work either:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700");
```

Please let me know how can I do it on Next version 13 and up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use Google fonts on a Next 13+ project you can do it this way:

*app/layout.js*

```
import { Poppins } from 'next/font/google';

const poppins = Poppins({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
  variable: '--font-poppins',
  weight: ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900']
});

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Page Title',
  description: 'Page Description',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html className={`${poppins.variable}`}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

And then in any CSS file you can use that font this way

```
.class {
  font-family: var(--font-poppins);
}
```

Comment: can you please give me an example of implementation using Poppins? Does it work for non google fonts?

Comment: `import { Poppins} from 'next/font/google'; const poppins = Poppins({ variable: '--font-poppins', });`

Then you can use it in your css files like this `font-family: var(--font-poppins);` or you can do something like this 
`<main className={poppins.variable}>`

Comment: That results with IDE complaining, "unresolved variable --font-poppins" in the CSS files

Answer (score 1):

Here is an official solution

[Nextjs tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/optimizing-fonts-images)

```js
import '@/app/ui/global.css';
import { inter } from '@/app/ui/fonts';
 
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} antialiased`}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```